# How to check a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the matrix $\left\{ \ \  \left.
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    x \\
    -y \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}  \ \  \right| \ x, y \in \mathbb{R} \  \right\}$
where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is $\mathcal{B} = \left\{ \ \ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, \ \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -1 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \ \ \right\} $ a basis for $W$?

My attempt: A basis of a subspace. If B is a subset of W, then we say that B is a basis for W if every vector in W can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in B.

Do I just show

$$W = b_1 (x) + b_2 (y) + b_3 (x)$$ yeah uhm idk

Comment: As for the latex editing, begin and end blocks with $, the left alignment of the matrices will follow.  Regarding the question, are the vectors of B, linearly independent?

Comment: I was going to edit your question, to improve the math display, however, I think this would be a good opportunity to help you some on your mathjax. First of all, whenever you use some command (starting with a '\'), you use '$'. If you want to type plain text, just do it as you would normaly do it. The dollar signs are only for typing something in 'mathmode' (such as matrices, etc.). For your other question, I will type an answer.

Comment: (Sorry, I think that learning by example might be easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the vectors in $\mathcal{B}$ aren't independent.

See that 
$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\-1 \\0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$ and thus we have linear dependence.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ x \\ -y 
\end{bmatrix} = x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
Therefore all vectors of $W$ can be written as a L.C of these 2 vectors. Say that the first vector is $v$ and the second is $u$. Note that your set of vectors given were: $u-v, v$ and $-u$. Since there are "unnecessary" vectors in that set ($u-v$), it is not a basis. Note also that you could simply state that $\operatorname{dim}W = 2$, therefore its basis must contain 2 elements. One can also see that this set is not linearly independent, therefore it can't be called a basis.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the vectors in the set $B$ are clearly in $W$ (by just plugging in the values). For your second question: Let me prove that the dimension of $W$ is 2: indeed, we have that $W$ only depends on 2 variables: $x, y$. Note that we can write the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
x\\
-y
\end{pmatrix}
= x 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
+ y
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
showing that you only need two vectors to describe all possible vectors in $W$. Hence the vectors in $B$ are linearly dependent (you have 3 vectors).

Another way to see this, is to note that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
-1\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
1\\
0\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
-1\\
0\\
1\end{pmatrix}$$
showing that the vectors are not linearly independent and hence don't form a basis of $W$.